# Does this Actor implementation has synchronization problems?

Tags: java, multithreading, actor

As a part of a job test, I wrote following implementation of the Actor execution model:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
public abstract class Actor implements Runnable {
  private final Executor executor;

  /** current token */
  private Message message=null;
  /** rest of tokens */
  private Queue<Message> queue = new LinkedList<Message>();

  private boolean isFired=false;

  public Actor(Executor executor) {
    this.executor = executor;
  }

  /** 
   * Frontend method which may be called from other Thread or Actor.
   * Saves the message and initiates Actor's execution.
   */
  protected void post(Message message) {
    synchronized(this) {
        if (isFired) {
            queue.add(message);
            return;
        }
        this.message=message;
        isFired=true; // to prevent multiple concurrent firings
    }
    executor.execute(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    for (;;) {
        this.message.run();
        synchronized(this) {
            this.message = queue.poll();  // consume token
            if (this.message==null) {
                isFired=false; // allow firing
                return;
            }
        }
    }
  }

  protected abstract class Message {
    protected abstract void run();
 }
}
```

Reviewers concluded, in particular, that "Actor class have synchronization issues", but did not want to explain why.

Can you see any synchronization problems here?

The code, along with a test, can be downloaded from https://github.com/rfqu/CodeSamples/tree/master/src/simpleactor.

Comment: You aren't being consistent with when you use `this.` to access a member variable. `run()` does not require `this.` to access message since there is not local variable with that name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem.. You `post()` your message and it gets assigned in `synchronized` block, but it gets *accessed* in non-synchronized block. The field is not `volatile` therefore even though the reference to `this.message` might be visible to ThreadB, the inner state of the object might be still invisible. So `message.run()` may get you into a trouble.

In order to make things right `this.message` should be marked as volatile. Read about [safe publishing in Java](https://www.google.com/#q=java+safe+publishing) for more details.

Comment: I've upvoted your post, it's a nice catch, but LMGTFY is rather rude so I've retraced my vote.

Comment: Another reference: *Java Concurrency in Practice*, *3.1.1. Stale Data*

Comment: When you suggest to make `this.message` volatile, you mean to make sure assigment to message `happens before` reading it. But as http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html reads, `Actions in a thread prior to submitting a Runnable object to an Executor happen-before its execution begins, perhaps in another thread`, so no need to make it volatile or   put another synchronized block.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov, nice catch!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any immediate synchronization issues. However that does not necessarily mean there aren't any. One synchronization design flaw is that you lock on `this`, which basically allows other classes to also acquire the lock, and screw with the inner workings of your implementation. Sometimes, you want to design a class like that, this is not such a case.

Secondly, you make things a bit complicated by having a `message` field, which basically acts as the head of the queue. The entire implemntation can do without it, and then also the need for `isFired` disappears.

Java also comes with a variety of Queue implementations that do synchronizing for you. In this case I'd replace the Linked List with a [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html), as it is also unbounded.

An internal lock can be used to make sure messages are not run concurrently.

So run() and post() would look like this :

```
private final Object lock = new Object();

@Override
public void run() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        Message message = queue.poll();
        if (message != null) {
            message.run();
        }
    }
}

protected final void post(Message message) {
    queue.add(message);
    executor.execute(this);
}
```

Note that I've also made `post()` and `run()` final, so subclasses cannot mess with the proper functioning of the `Actor` behavior.

Comment: The way you did post() make executing of different messages parallel, which does not comply with the Actor model. I used own synchronization instead of synchronized queue in order to avoid parallel executions of the same actor instance. The isFired variable used as an indicator that this instance is being executed and should not be submitted to the executor once again. Indeed, synchronizing on an internal object, inaccessible outside the actor instance, would be better.

Comment: In fact, isFired==true just when message!=null, so one of them (but not both) can be eliminated. I preferred to retain message to avoid linking/delinking when message rate is low - see updated version on github.

Comment: I've edited the answer to address avoiding concurrent execution of messages. Avoiding linking/delinking sounds like premature optimization.

Comment: the edited answer has severe drawback - it calls message.run() under closed lock, blocking all threads in the thread pool except one, thus making any pool a single-threaded one.

Comment: It will only block other threads that attempt to acquire the same lock. The pool is fine.

Comment: Let you have N threads in the pool, and send M>N messages to the same actor. Then all threads except one would be blocked.

Comment: I thought you wanted it so, that messages on the same actor do not execute concurrently, in fact, what you describe is true for your original solution as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9724/discussion-between-bowmore-and-alexei-kaigorodov)

Answer (score 1):

There is unsafe publication problem exists. You create "queue" in unsynchronized block and read it in synchronized block, so due to reordering "queue" maybe null or uncomplettly initialized when execution of "post" method happen.

To solve this problem just make "queue" final([JMM 17.5. final Field Semantics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5)) or do on-demand initalization in "post" method.

Answer (score 0):

As your code is now, the following can happen:

1. `post(Message message)` is called and completes.
2. `post(Message message)` is called again.
3. The thread started by 1. (in `executor.execute(this)`) starts -- and processes the message from 2. However, it does **not** get a chance to enter the synchronized block.
4. The thread started by 2. (in `executor.execute(this)`) starts -- and **reprocesses** the message from 2.

and so forth.

Comment: I cannot agree with your scenario. First, messages are processed in order, so the thread started from 1) first processes the message saved in the variable `message` by the step 1), not by the step 2). Second, step 2 does not start new thread because `isFired==true`. This variable guarantees that at most one thread at a time processes messages. And after `message.run();`, processing thread unconditionally enters synchronized block - why do you claim that `it does not get a chance to enter the synchronized block`?

Comment: There is no guarantee as to when a thread will execute, or sleep.

Comment: If you want to prove the code assumes some timing, then place Thread.sleep() everywhere, construct desired timing and show that, say, second message is processed twice.

Comment: I agree with Alexei.  If you are at step 3 then it means that `isFired` is true, so if another message arrives (step 4), it will never call `executor.execute(this)`.  Look at `post(message)` more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a major synchronization flaw.

**However**, your code won't run all messages on the same thread if there is some long pauses between messages.  Then `executor.execute(this)` will be called many times and it could start any thread if the `executor` has more than one thread.

I believe that an actor should run on the same thread all the time.  I'm not sure about this, and the documentation in wikipedia does not seem to support this.  That would be relevant for example if the actor maintains a counter of all messages it received.

**Anti-However**: I don't even see how your code would fail even in such a case because of the Java memory model: every time you call `synchronized` the memory is flushed, so the counter (or whatever) would be kept current across all (sequentially executed) threads nonetheless.)

Comment: "actor should run on the same thread all the time" - very intriguing statement. Do you have any reason for this?

Comment: I gave the example with the counter and I guess there are many similar cases.  However, if it is possible an actor should not keep any inner state.

Comment: Do you think actor's state is saved in a thread? This is simply wrong. Actor's state and executing thread have no connection (unless connection organized artificially), so changing threads does not affect actor's state. And, stateless actors have little sense.

Comment: If your actors have some state then you must explicitly synchronize that too.  It might be simpler to then just run an actor in the same thread (maybe many actors on one thread).  But as I explained in my post, I believe the synchronization will be correct in your code, even if there is state, just from the Java memory model and your calls to `synchronized`.